# What is the benefit of increasing on-board graphics card allocated memory from BIOS?

Tags: bios, intel-graphics, memory-management

In my BIOS settings I can set my Intel graphics card's memory from the default 256 MB to 512 MB. My laptop has a dedicated graphics card as well.

Should I? What would I gain?
Are there any downsides?

Answer (score 0):

That greatly depend of your card.

For modern intel internal card you should increase memory only if you are going to use it in hi-demending games.

Since you say you have dedicated grafic, you need intel card memory only for 2D operation. So it is safe to put memory to 32 or even 16M if option availible. Your memory will depend of your screen size and resolution in 2D. One buffer take X*Y*2 bytes. In most applications you not need more then 2 buffers.

For full-hd monitor 1920×1080 you need 4Mb ram(so 16 will be enought unless you have dual monitor configuration).

Comment: Most modern monitors use 32 bits per pixel for colour, meaning X*Y*4. Also, RAM is allocated in megabytes, not megabits as you indicate.

Comment: Hi. I've got the main laptop monitor which is indeed 1920x1080 and it's what I use at home. At the office I use a larger one, 2560x1600. Rarely dual-screen, but can happen.

Comment: so you need 32-64RAM maximum. if you second card not used, likly it still used for second monitor. Anyway you not need 256MB for 2D

Comment: It should be noted that some notebook GPU's do not render for external monitors, so it'd be solely the onboard graphics handling it.